# Should entropy be always extensive?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, identical-particles

My question came up from the discussion in class which is about whether we should treat a specific system distinguishable or indistinguishable. To figure out what will happen in these two circumstances, I calculated a system of classical N identical harmonics oscillators by using microcanonical ensemble, and something unexpected happens. When I treat the system be distinguishable, everything is fine, I get an extensive entropy. But when I treat this system be indistinguishable, I get an extra term $Nlog(N)-N$ (Stirling approximation), which make the entropy not extensive any more.

My question is why this happens, should entropy be always extensive? or it's related to how we treat the system(i.e it will be decided by whether we treat a system distinguishable). And also, if entropy is always extensive (which I think should be), then is the derivation above claims the incompleteness of statitical mechanics?

Comment: Which definition of "extensive" are you using here?

Comment: Well, I think it's the most normal one, which indicate $S(nV, nE, nN)=nS(V, E, N)$ where we used Boltzman definition of entropy.

Comment: Particles are believed to be distinguishable or indistinguishable, not systems...